Estimating the cost for Terraform Cloud
I am estimating the cost of resources in GCP. My plan uses asset inventory in GCP to summarize all resources used in a project. As far as I know, Terraform Cloud calculates costs based on resources > 500. Therefore, can I use "asset inventory" for evaluating?
Hope people support me!
